# cant seem to fix my mute command Discord JS

Tags: discord.js

for some reason i keep getting this error i cant seem to get my mute command to work without giving me a error tried everything i could to fix it this looks bout right to me if you could help me please let me know thanks the error is at the bottom of the code block

This is the code as well

```js
const ms = require('ms');
module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: "This mutes a member",
    execute(message, args) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {

            let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'member');
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'mute');

            let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

            if (!args[1]) {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted`);
                return
            }
            memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`);

            setTimeout(function() {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
            }, ms(args[1]));
        } else {
            message.channel.send('Cant find that member!');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error

```js
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\commands\mute.js:6
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\commands\mute.js:6:41)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\events\guild\message.js:10:26)
    at Client.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot>
```

Comment: What is the error? Just saying "for some reason i keep getting this error" doesn't give us enough information to help with anything

Comment: its at the very bottom on the code block

Comment: i just re did the thing so it should be easier to see

Comment: Not all messages have mentions, you should be checking first with something like `const target = message.mentions?.users?.first(); if (target) { /* something */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove the `target` constant variable and do something like this:

```
const memberTarget = message.mentions.members.first() // returns the first mention but as a member
if(!memberTarget) return message.channel.send('Mention a user.') // Checks if there is a mentioned member, if there is not the bot will send a message in the channel saying 'Mention a user'
```